# Increment the position by 1 when saving, Spring Boot, MongoDb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to increment the position by 1 when it is saved. I want to do this to sort the card, change the position of each card.

It is like generating a sequence starting with 1, putting only when it is saved.

```
@Document
public class Card {
    @Id private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private Long positionSequence = 1L; //increment the position 1 when saved
    //getter, setter
}
```

MongoDb doesn't have @PrePersist Like JPA, I thought about extending the AbstractMongoEventListener and using the BeforeConvertEvent to increment each position. It's a good idea?

```
@Override
    public void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent<Card> event) {
        Card card = event.getSource();
        if (card.getId() == null) {
            card.setPositionSequence(positionSequence++);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can create a sequence in your database and increment it when need.

Comment: May be this tutorial will help: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-mongodb-auto-generated-field